# How to add Jquery or javascript functions for click to popup open?

Tags: popup

[popup images I need to click to menu items popup show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqSZj.png)

Comment: can you please add some details or share your codes so that it'll be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for helping me #atiquratik. It's working now. I have no word. I'm so much happy. thanks bro .

Comment: It's work. I need is will be default none. when I click the items then showing the right popup.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide popup content initially using CSS & then use jQuery `fadeIn()`/ `fadeOut()` to show/hide popup respectively.

Sample HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="click-to-open">click to open popup</a>

<div class="popup-content"> <!-- use display:none to hide initially -->
  <a href="#" class="popup-close">x</a>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p> 
</div>
```

jQuery click function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.click-to-open').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.popup-content').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.popup-close').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.popup-content').fadeOut();
   }
});
```

Check the following fiddle for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/tvaunsg3/1/

You can use `toggleClass()` on `body` to create some overlay while pop-up is active.

Alternatively, you can also use [jQuery Modal](https://jquerymodal.com/) or [Magnific Popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) if you need more advanced functionality (callback and etc).